# Please delete this answer

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

> [image]
>
> (Question)
>
> [image]
>
> (Answer)
>
> [image]
>
> (VLQ and NAA flags, why was the VLQ declined?)

The answer doesn't seem to answer the question, and even it might be an answer, it looks dirty and needs to be removed.

Link to answer: https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/39529/25526

Comment: "it looks dirty" What?!?!

Comment: @yannis i mean... it either does not answer the question or has severe content problems.  I raised both NAA and VLQ flags, but nothing was working.  It looks dirty means it has very serious content or formatting problems and needs to be removed.  That is what I am saying.

Comment: Please be specific. What exactly are the "very serious content or formatting problems" you are talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer in question repeats a part of the accepted answer (which seems was posted first as well). So it's not adding much if anything, but there are no specific flags for "duplicate answers". It does seem to be "gaming the system" to gain easy rep without saying anything new, so I've downvoted and VTD as well (it appears I'm the 2nd VTD).

Comment: That is a very good point and a good reason to vote to delete the answer. A custom mod flag explaining the answer only repeats an earlier one would have been very helpful here. Even a comment identifying the actual issue would help.

Answer (score 7):

The question asks for a term. The answer offers just that. It certainly isn't a great answer, probably not even a good one, but it is an answer nonetheless.

I see no reason to remove it. If you feel the answer is not helpful, downvote it and move on.